# How to post in a popup page using a link in a template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, gridview, popup

I have the following case :

My current grid view is like this :

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px">
<ItemTemplate>
<a id="btnShowPopup5" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='<%#"PopUpPage.aspx?TCode="+Eval("t_code")+"&TransSerial="+Eval("t_s")+"&AR=2"+"&TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750"%>'
```

---

this link opens a popup page which load a specific user control .

Now i want to pass these parameters in the post instead of the query string , cuz i find it more secure.

I create form like this :

```
 <form id="frm_popup" method="post" target="_blank" action="https://..../PopUpPage.aspx">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_task_code" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_trans_serial" runat="server" />
 </form>
```

I try to set the hidden fields but i can't because there's no command name for the link .

My question is how to post in a popup page using a link in a template field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the form in a js function and pass parameters to it:

```
function postForm(tcode, t_s)
{
    $('#<%=hf_task_code.ClientID%>').val(tcode);
    $('#<%=hf_trans_serial.ClientID%>').val(t_s);
    $('#frm_popup').submit();
}

<a id="btnShowPopup5" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='#' 
   onclick='<%# "postForm(\"" + Eval("t_code") + "\",\"" + Eval("t_s") + "\")")%>' />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but when i try this method , it doesn't enter the page_load of `Popuppage.aspx` .it instead  load the main page again in the pop up !!!